# OpenGL segfaults on OSX but works fine on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, macos, opengl

I have started developing an OpenGL (ES) application which will run on both Raspberry Pi and OS X. I'v based my starting point on the "triangle" example which ships with rasbian. This example displays a rotating cube with mapped textures. It uses specific broadcom functions to initialize the context. For OSX i'v used the appropriate GLUT functions. I have split the init functions out for osx vs pi and the pi version works fine. When I run the osx version, I always get a segfault on glDrawArrays() calls within redraw_scene().  Normally the cause of this is incorrect vertex data. But as mentioned the same code (in relation to setting up and drawing) works on the Pi. This is a trimmed version of the code which demonstrates the error. Perhaps there is something I need do differently for regular OpenGL vs ES?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

typedef struct {
   uint32_t screen_width;
   uint32_t screen_height;
   GLuint tex[6];
   GLfloat rot_angle_x_inc;
   GLfloat rot_angle_y_inc;
   GLfloat rot_angle_z_inc;
   GLfloat rot_angle_x;
   GLfloat rot_angle_y;
   GLfloat rot_angle_z;
   GLfloat distance;
   GLfloat distance_inc;
   char *tex_buf1;
   char *tex_buf2;
   char *tex_buf3;
} CUBE_STATE_T;

static CUBE_STATE_T _state, *state=&_state;

#define IMAGE_SIZE 128

const GLbyte quadx[6*4*3] = {
    -10, -10,  10, 10, -10,  10, -10,  10,  10, 10,  10,  10, -10, -10, -10, -10,  10, -10, 10, -10, -10, 10,  10, -10,
    -10, -10,  10, -10,  10,  10, -10, -10, -10, -10,  10, -10, 10, -10, -10, 10,  10, -10, 10, -10,  10, 10,  10,  10,
    -10,  10,  10, 10,  10,  10, -10,  10, -10, 10,  10, -10, -10, -10,  10, -10, -10, -10, 10, -10,  10, 10, -10, -10
};

const GLfloat texCoords[6 * 4 * 2] = {
    0.f,  0.f, 0.f,  1.f, 1.f,  0.f, 1.f,  1.f, 0.f,  0.f, 0.f,  1.f, 1.f,  0.f, 1.f,  1.f,
    0.f,  0.f, 0.f,  1.f, 1.f,  0.f, 1.f,  1.f, 0.f,  0.f, 0.f,  1.f, 1.f,  0.f, 1.f,  1.f,
    0.f,  0.f, 0.f,  1.f, 1.f,  0.f, 1.f,  1.f, 0.f,  0.f, 0.f,  1.f, 1.f,  0.f, 1.f,  1.f
};

void reshapeView(int width, int height);
void drawView();
void update_model();
void redraw_scene();

char * junk() {
    // dont load real images just make some random junk
    int image_sz = IMAGE_SIZE*IMAGE_SIZE*3;
    char * texture = (char*)malloc(image_sz);
    for (int x=0;x<image_sz;x++) {
        texture[x] = (char)x;
    }
    return texture;
}

void create() {
    char * myargv [1];
    int myargc = 1;
    myargv[0] = strdup("view");
    glutInit(&myargc, myargv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("window");
    glutFullScreen();

    state->tex_buf1 = junk();
    state->tex_buf2 = junk();
    state->tex_buf3 = junk();

    glGenTextures(6, &state->tex[0]);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 0,
                 GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, state->tex_buf1);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[1]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 0,
                 GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, state->tex_buf1);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[2]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 0,
                 GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, state->tex_buf2);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[3]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 0,
                 GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, state->tex_buf2);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[4]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 0,
                 GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, state->tex_buf3);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[5]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 0,
                 GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, state->tex_buf3);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, (GLfloat)GL_NEAREST);

    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeView);
    glutDisplayFunc(drawView);
    glutIdleFunc(drawView);
}

void reshapeView(int width, int height) {
    state->screen_width = width;
    state->screen_height = height;

    glHint( GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST );
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)state->screen_width, (GLsizei)state->screen_height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float nearp = 1.0f;
    float farp = 500.0f;
    float hht = nearp * (float)tan(45.0 / 2.0 / 180.0 * 3.141592654);
    float hwd = hht * (float)state->screen_width / (float)state->screen_height;

    glFrustum(-hwd, hwd, -hht, hht, nearp, farp);

    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 3, GL_BYTE, 0, quadx );

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, -50.f);

    state->rot_angle_x = 45.f;
    state->rot_angle_y = 30.f;
    state->rot_angle_z = 0.f;
    state->rot_angle_x_inc = 0.5f;
    state->rot_angle_y_inc = 0.5f;
    state->rot_angle_z_inc = 0.f;
    state->distance = 40.f;
}

void drawView() {
    update_model();
    redraw_scene();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void update_model() {
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, -state->distance);

    glRotatef(state->rot_angle_x, 1.0f, 0.f, 0.f);
    glRotatef(state->rot_angle_y, 0.f, 1.0f, 0.f);
    glRotatef(state->rot_angle_z, 0.f, 0.f, 1.0f);
}

void redraw_scene() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[0]);
    glRotatef(270.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f ); // front face normal along z axis
    // ZOMG segfaults here!!! 
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[1]);
    glRotatef(90.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f ); // back face normal along z axis
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[2]);
    glRotatef(90.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f ); // left face normal along x axis
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[3]);
    glRotatef(90.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f ); // right face normal along x axis
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 12, 4);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[4]);
    glRotatef(270.f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f ); // top face normal along y axis
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, state->tex[5]);
    glRotatef(90.f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f ); // bottom face normal along y axis
    glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);
}

int main() {
    create();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

CMake file...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(jni)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -Wno-deprecated -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    demo.cpp
)

add_executable(demo.bin ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: So is it C++ or C you are using? Also what standard? The code definitely looks like C.

Comment: sorry, my code is c++ but i stripped the example down to c. i'll edit the tags

Comment: Try seeing what `glGetError()` returns right before the segfault happens.

Comment: 1280 Invalid Enum. I printed it at various lines and the error is on glVertexPointer( 3, GL_BYTE, 0, quadx );

Comment: FOUND IT. :) OSX doesnt support GL_BYTE vertex data. Changed it to GL_INTEGER and it worked. Thanks @tambre that tip about the glGetError() is very handy. You can answer this question if you like and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: Answered the question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the return value of `glGetError()` right before the segfault to determine what went wrong. The segfault may be caused by the driver or the graphics card not supporting certain types of OpenGL operations.

Comment: Thanks.  I used glGetError() to find the call which failed and found OSX doesnt support GL_BYTE vertex data. (Or that's to say ES does) I changed it to GL_INTEGER and it worked.